# Mocking controller in sprinng boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a spring boot test, to test one of my endpoints. Here is the workflow I have running instance of my spring boot app and I want to test this endpoint when the spring boot app is running. In the business layer of this endpoint, we have logic calling external endpoint and I created I mock controller, but I'm facing this error:

```
2023-03-19 00:21:22.082  INFO 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-03-19 00:21:22.082  INFO 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-03-19 00:21:22.087 DEBUG 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 1 mappings in 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping'
2023-03-19 00:21:22.091 DEBUG 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: none
2023-03-19 00:21:22.094 DEBUG 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: none
2023-03-19 00:21:22.095 DEBUG 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-03-19 00:21:22.095  INFO 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 13 ms
2023-03-19 00:21:22.109 DEBUG 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : POST "/blueprint/callback", parameters={}
2023-03-19 00:21:22.116 DEBUG 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.vmware.tango.integration.mock.MockBlueprintController#callback()
2023-03-19 00:21:22.116 DEBUG 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Failed to complete request: java.lang.NullPointerException
2023-03-19 00:21:22.119 ERROR 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.getHandler(TestDispatcherServlet.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Here is the test class:

```
@Log4j2
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { WebSecurityConfig.class,  WebConfiguration.class },
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureWebClient
public class WorkflowTest {
}
```

WebConfugartion.class

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
    }

}
```

I want to mention that this class is in separate module

Comment: You should definitely post a [mre] in your question (as text).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating a mock endpoint, you can try with a wiremock: Program it to have the same URL as the external endpoint and return a mock response.

Something like this:

```
WireMockServer wms = new WireMockServer({port $})
wms.start()
WireMock.configureFor(url, port)
WireMock.stubFor(
            WireMock.({http method name})()(WireMock.urlEqualTo('/'+suffix)). 
                .willReturn(
                    WireMock.aResponse(responseString(=Json string of return object, can be null))
                        .withBody()
                        .withStatus(statusCode)
            )
        );
```

Then run your test normally; you won't need the mock controller. Not the ideal way to unit test stuff but it should get the job done.

Comment: WireMock is a common tool/framework to test a integration layer from App A to B using REST APi. If you want to test URLs, Response, client config/security thats the way. For Unit-Tests ofcasue you use mocks instead and not wiremock. Just should start on WebMvc/SpringBoot Tests in that context. Just as info.

Answer (score 0):

in your code example, @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) is useless,
as you put @SpringBootTest annotation over WorkflowTest class and it already contains @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class).

Comment: That's a valid comment but not the problems solution/answer.

Comment: i can't add just comment with my new low reputation. obliged to answer in this area..